# My Android Application When I want to move From LoginActivity to RegisterActivity

Tags: java, android

My Android App says unfortunately androidAppName has stopped responding whenever I clicked the regsiter button towhen I want to move from the LoginActivity to RegisterActivity

Here is the Logcat error message shown below:

```
 03-03 03:41:02.541 1473-32321/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -m 31808 -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Here is my activity_login.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context="com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars.LoginActivity"
    android:background="#555d7b"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FF00FF"
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etUsername"
        android:background="#ff00ff"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@id/etPassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:onClick="forgotPasswordHandler"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvFPassword"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:text="login"
        android:background="#44ddee"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvFPassword"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:onClick="loginHandler"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSignup"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#44ddee"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="signupHandler"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvSignup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is also my LoginActivity.java

```
    package com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private EditText inputUsername, inputPassword;
    private TextView forgotPassword, signup;
    private Button login;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        forgotPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFPassword);
        signup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSignup);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }

    public void signuHandler(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
    }


    public void forgotPasswordHandler(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
    }

    public void loginHandler(View view) {

        String email = inputUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //authenticate user
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // there was an error
                            if (password.length() < 6) {
                                inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new 

Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent
            finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });


        }
}
```

Here is my Stacktrace

```
03-03 03:41:02.541 1473-32321/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -m 31808 -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
03-03 03:48:29.317 4908-4908/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
03-03 03:48:29.317 4908-4908/? D/FA: Debug logging enabled
03-03 03:55:39.807 5120-5120/? I/GAv4: Google Analytics 7.5.71 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
                                         adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
                                         adb logcat -s GAv4
03-03 03:57:31.716 5446-5446/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
03-03 03:57:31.716 5446-5446/? D/FA: Debug logging enabled
03-03 03:57:40.204 5625-5625/? I/AS.: 03:57:40.208[1] Logger Started, DebugVersion = false
03-03 04:01:27.956 5942-5985/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.Debug.startMethodTracingSampling, referenced from method com.facebook.trace.DebugTracer.a
03-03 04:01:27.956 5942-5985/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 723: Landroid/os/Debug;.startMethodTracingSampling (Ljava/lang/String;II)V
03-03 04:01:32.451 6129-6129/? I/AS.: 04:01:32.464[1] Logger Started, DebugVersion = false
03-03 04:03:31.837 6417-6417/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
03-03 04:03:31.837 6417-6417/? D/FA: Debug logging enabled
03-03 04:13:30.461 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:30.491 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:30.862 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:30.872 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:31.062 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:31.082 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:32.253 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:32.263 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:32.443 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:32.453 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:35.997 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:36.007 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:37.919 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:37.929 1769-1769/? I/SamsungIME: getDebugLevel  : 0x4f4c
03-03 04:13:43.334 6680-6680/com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
03-03 04:13:43.374 6680-6680/com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                     adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars
03-03 04:13:43.374 6680-6680/com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
03-03 04:13:43.634 6680-6680/com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-03 04:13:46.207 1473-6758/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -m 6680 -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
03-03 04:14:18.668 7267-7306/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.Debug.startMethodTracingSampling, referenced from method com.facebook.trace.DebugTracer.a
03-03 04:14:18.668 7267-7306/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 723: Landroid/os/Debug;.startMethodTracingSampling (Ljava/lang/String;II)V
03-03 04:25:21.515 11430-11430/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-03 04:25:22.646 11445-11445/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-03 04:25:33.156 11468-11468/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-03 04:25:42.606 11531-11531/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-03 04:25:44.247 11560-11560/com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
03-03 04:25:44.497 11560-11560/com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                       adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars
03-03 04:25:44.497 11560-11560/com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
03-03 04:25:44.968 11560-11560/com.geekbounty.nigerianscholars D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-03 04:25:47.470 11668-11695/? I/GAv4: Google Analytics 8.4.87 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
                                           adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
                                           adb logcat -s GAv4
03-03 04:25:48.551 11738-11738/? I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
03-03 04:25:51.484 11845-11845/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-03 04:25:52.755 11820-11820/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.Debug.startMethodTracingSampling, referenced from method com.facebook.trace.DebugTracer.a
03-03 04:25:52.755 11820-11820/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 723: Landroid/os/Debug;.startMethodTracingSampling (Ljava/lang/String;II)V
03-03 04:25:59.973 12069-12069/? I/GAv4: Google Analytics 7.5.71 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
                                           adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
                                           adb logcat -s GAv4
03-03 04:26:07.690 1473-12355/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -m 11560 -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: can you post your stack trace?

Comment: here is my Stacktrace

Comment: have you declare the RegisterActivity in the menifest?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i just found your problem. There is just a typo there on the method name. Change

```
public void signuHandler(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
}
```

to

```
public void signupHandler(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have done that but still gives me the same headache

Comment: is it ok when you click forgot password?

Comment: Have you declared RegisterActivity to manifest? I don't see anything else wrong there. Is there no error stack trace when your application force closed?

Comment: I have the RegisterActivity in the manifest. moreso I have editted the post above with the stacktrace